# I have a docker-compose file when i am running i am seeing below error can some one help on it

Tags: docker-compose

When I'm trying to build seeing below error. Tried changing multiple version also but no use.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Invalid top-level property "worker". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services, networks, volumes, secrets, configs, and extensions starting with "x-".
>
> You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
>   For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

below is my compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres: 
    image: 'postgres:latest'
  redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
  nginx:
    restart: always  
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment: 
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
client:
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    context: ./client
  volumes:
    -  /app/node_modules
    - ./client:/app
worker:
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    context: ./worker
  volumes: 
    - /app/node_modules
    - ./worker:/app
```

Comment: The YAML file isn't valid. Please check the indentation on `client:` and below (put two more spaces on every line on `client:` and below).

Comment: added  can you check once i have checked with yaml lint its is perfect

Comment: But it is not perfect for docker. see my comment above. The `client:` and `worker:` have to be under services (not on the same level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an indentation issue with the docker-compose file. 'worker' and 'clients' are services and as such must be under 'services' as children. The below should work.

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres: 
    image: 'postgres:latest'
  redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
  nginx:
    restart: always  
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment: 
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      -  /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
  worker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
    volumes: 
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./worker:/app
```

Comment: Thank you, working fine though I have cross verified indentation anyhow thankyou

Comment: what error? Also, if the solution works for you, you might want to accept the solution as the answer.